# How to have "always allow on chess.com" option be enabled by default for a firefox extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am making a firefox extension for chess.com. It works well;however, the user must right click the extension and then select "always allow on chess.com" for it to work.

Otherwise the extension does not work, and there is a green dot you have to click for it to run. I would like to be able to prompt the user to enable this option, or I would like to be able to enable it by default.

This is my manifest.json. I have set the host_permissions, but it still does not work.

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Name",
    "version": "2.1",
    "permissions": [
        "storage"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://api.chess.com/*",
        "*://*.chess.com/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://www.chess.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
    "action": {
        "default_icon": "knook.png",
        "default_popup": "options.html"
    },
    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html"
    },
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "identifier@name.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to do what you described normally in Chrome, so it's either a bug in Firefox or maybe you accidentally switched the extension into on-click mode inside `about:addons`.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I think it may be a bug in firefox. I downgraded to manifest V2 instead of V3, and now it works fine.